# Keep feature branch up to date with feature base branch

Tags: git

Sometimes the feature getting big while I code it. So I split it into the second branch.
When the core feature branch waiting for review, I'm working on the second branch implementing other functionalities for the feature.

After review, I'm coming back to the core feature branch and refactorize it then switch to the second branch and merge code with changes, but after merge the core branch my merge request of the second branch has changes that I implemented in the core branch of this feature.

To illustrate what I mean look at the flow below:

starting from branch: **development**

```sh
git checkout -b feature/user-profile-selection #create core branch of feature
```

Now I'm coding...
After few commits, I'm ready to let the team review my code:

```sh
git push #create merge request
```

Now I'm creating new branch from: *feature/user-profile-selection* branch

```sh
git checkout -b feature/user-profile-selection-animations
```

Now doing some commits...
After any time the core feature branch merge request is ready to refactorize.
I'm switching back to branch: feature/user-profile-selection
Doing changes, push and merge to the development branch.

After this I'm switching back to the feature/user-profile-selection-animations and merge development branch to it.

And now when I create merge request of feature/user-profile-selection-animations branch to branch development, I see commits from core branch *feature/user-profile-selection*

How can I get rid of these commits and changes from core branch that was merged?

Comment: Do you do any rebasing or amends on the original branch?

Comment: Also, how do you merge PRs? Hopefully not a squash merge. `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` would help. Just the parts which connect to development and feature/user-profile-selection.

Comment: @Schwern It possibly could be any rebased on development.
And all merge request are merged with --squash flag

Comment: Ahh, squash merge. There's your problem. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this as "anticipating a merge".

After branching and working you have this.

```
A - B - C [development]
         \
          D - E - F [feature/user-profile-selection]
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

But you're also still working on feature/user-profile-selection, so it becomes this.

```
A - B - C [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K [feature/user-profile-selection]
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

> After any time the core feature branch merge request is ready to refactorize. I'm switching back to branch: feature/user-profile-selection Doing changes, push and merge to the development branch.

```
$ git checkout development
$ git merge feature/user-profile-selection
$ git branch -d feature/user-profile-selection

A - B - C ----------------- M [development]
         \                 /
          D - E - F - J - K
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

> After this I'm switching back to the feature/user-profile-selection-animations and merge development branch to it.

```
$ git checkout feature/user-profile-selection-animations
$ git merge development

A - B - C ----------------- M [development]
         \                 / \
          D - E - F - J - K   \
                   \           \
                    G - H - I - N [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

> And now when I create merge request of feature/user-profile-selection-animations branch to branch development, I see commits from core branch feature/user-profile-selection

Normally there wouldn't be. When you merge, Git will only include the commits whic are reachable from feature/user-profile-selection-animations which are not also reachable from development. That's G - H - I.

That's a normal merge workflow. But that's not what happened.

---

> all merge request are merged with --squash flag

There's your problem. Let's go back to just before the first branch was merged.

```
A - B - C [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K [feature/user-profile-selection]
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

A squash merge smashes D - E - F - J -K into a new commit and slaps that onto development.

```
$ git checkout development
$ git merge --squash feature/user-profile-selection-animations
$ git branch -D feature/user-profile-selection

A - B - C - SM [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

You then merge development into the other branch.

```
$ git checkout feature/user-profile-selection-animations
$ git merge development

A - B - C - SM -------------* [development]
         \                   \
          D - E - F - J - K   \
                   \           \
                    G - H - I - N [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

When you go to merge feature/user-profile-selection-animations into development, Git will select the commits which are reachable from feature/user-profile-selection-animations but not from development. This is and G - H - I, but *also* the old D - E - F. Git doesn't know that SM has the content of D - E - F.

How do you fix this? ***Don't squash merge***. It might seem like it simplifies things, but it doesn't. Every merge rewrites history causing issues like you are having.

Worse, it destroys vital detail about why changes were made. In the future, you will want to know why code is written the way it is. With a normal merge, each line is associated with its last commit describing what was done. With a squash merge, each line is associated with a whole branch's worth of commits. All those careful, detailed explanations are smashed together and it's unclear what log message relates to what change.

---

In general, once the anticipated parent branch has been merged I find it best to start over fresh and *rebase* the branch as if it was written on top of development all along.

Let's go back to just after the squash merge.

```
A - B - C - SM [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
```

Instead of merging development into feature/user-profile-selection-animations, let's rebase it onto development.

If you do `git rebase development` you'll have the same problem, it will drag the old D - E - F commits with it. Instead, tell Git to only take G - H - I.

```
# git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream-commit> <branch>
$ git rebase --onto development F feature/user-profile-selection-animations

              G1 - H1 - I1 [feature/user-profile-selection-animations]
             /
A - B - C - SM [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K
                   \
                    G - H - I
```

There's [an example of this in `git-rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description).

Now its as if feature/user-profile-selection-animations was written on top of development all along. History is clean. The merge will be clean. The original commits will eventually be garbage collected.

```
$ git checkout development 
$ git merge --no-ff feature/user-profile-selection-animations
$ git branch -d feature/user-profile-selection-animations

              G1 - H1 - I1
             /            \
A - B - C - SM ----------- O [development]
         \
          D - E - F - J - K
                   \
                    G - H - I
```

I used `git merge --no-ff` (no fast forward) to ensure there is a merge commit even if one is needed. Now it's clear what commits were done together in a branch (a "feature bubble") while keeping history linear.

This is the default Github PR merge behavior.